# How do I implement weka classifier MPL in matlab

Tags: matlab, weka

hi : i m working with matlab 2014a and i need to implement MULTIPERCEPTRON classification algorithme from weka 3.6  to matlab .
I have dificulties to find the setting of the classifier

```
classifier=javaObject('weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron');
classifier.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions(' -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a'));
```

and i m getting this error

```
>  Java exception occurred: java.lang.Exception: Illegal options:  -L
> 0.3  -M
>  0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a  at
>      weka.core.Utils.checkForRemainingOptions(Utils.java:534)     at  weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron.setOptions(MultilayerPerceptron.java:2376)
```